# my system is not restarting

Tags: system, shutdown

I clicked shutdown and then clicked restart and also tried shutdown. But it is not shutting down. I don't want to force shutdown by the power button. Last time I did that the system files got damaged and I had to reinstall the system. So, what options I have?

I even tried command 'shutdown' from the terminal. It is not working too.

Comment: This could happen due to a pending install. Please check if you have any pending install on AppCenter. Or perform an update on terminal and let me know what you see.